# TestNG @Test(invocationCount = 20) to a Class with @Test(DataProvider="someList") to a Method

Tags: java, testing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a TestNG test Suit for a JAVA Project and, In there I have a

**@Test(DataProvider="ListOfObjects")** annotated Method. Which provides method with around 20 rows of data.( Hence the method runs 20 times.) 
  Now, I want to run this class for **2hrs (part of SOAK related test.)** On average the Class takes around 10 mins for single run. So I am thinking or running the whole class for 12 times, and thus thinking of using **@Test(invocationCount = 20) on the Class itself**.
Any Better Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Found an Embarrassingly simple solution: 
Repeating the whole Test Suit as follows

```
@Test
public void RepeatTestSuite() {
    long startTime = new Date().getTime();
    while(!isTestFinished(startTime)) {

          List<String> suites = new ArrayList<String>();
             suites.add("./SOAK_all41.xml"); //path of .xml file to be run-provide complete path

             TestNG tng = new TestNG();
             tng.setTestSuites(suites);

             tng.run(); //run test suite
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the test in a method, then create a test method with a reasonably high invocation count. In that test method, compare the time with a variable holding the timestamp of the first run and if it has run for more than 20 minutes skip the test.

Comment: I have more than 10  such classes and within each class there are at least 3 of such methods. These are divided based on there Devicetype(IoT). I don't think I can extract tests in one method.